# Getting error when testing the Svm Model for Object Detection

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, anaconda, jupyter, svm

```
from skimage.transform import pyramid_gaussian
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from skimage import color
from skimage import io
from imutils.object_detection import non_max_suppression
import imutils
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import glob 


orientations = 9
pixels_per_cell = (8, 8)
cells_per_block = (2, 2)
threshold = .3


def sliding_window(image, stepSize, windowSize):
    for y in range(0, image.shape[0], stepSize):
        for x in range(0, image.shape[1], stepSize):
            yield (x, y, image[y: y + windowSize[1], x:x + windowSize[0]])

 model = joblib.load('model_name.npy')

scale = 0
detections = []

img= cv2.imread("pos\56_resized.jpg")


(winW, winH)= (180,320)
windowSize=(winW,winH)
downscale=1.5
for resized in pyramid_gaussian(img, downscale=1.5):
    for (x,y,window) in sliding_window(resized, stepSize=10, windowSize=(winW,winH)):
        if window.shape[0] != winH or window.shape[1] !=winW:
            continue
        window=color.rgb2gray(window)
        fds = hog(window, orientations, pixels_per_cell, cells_per_block, block_norm='L2')
        fds = fds.reshape(1, -1)
        pred = model.predict(fds)

        if pred == 1:
            if model.decision_function(fds) > 0.6:
                print("Detection:: Location -> ({}, {})".format(x, y))
                print("Scale ->  {} | Confidence Score {} \n".format(scale,model.decision_function(fds)))
                detections.append((int(x*(downscale**scale)),int(y*(downscale**scale)),model.decision_function(fds),int(windowSize[0]*(downscale**scale)),int(windowSize[1]*(downscale**scale))
    scale+=1
```

> **  ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)  in 
>   ----> 1 for img1 in pyramid_gaussian(img, downscale=2):
>         2     for (x,y,window) in sliding_window(resized, stepSize=10, windowSize=(winW,winH)):
>         3         if window.shape[0] != winH or window.shape[1] !=winW:
>         4             continue
>         5         window=color.rgb2gray(window)
>
> D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\transform\pyramids.py in
>   pyramid_gaussian(image, max_layer, downscale, sigma, order, mode,
>   cval, multichannel)
>       195 
>       196     # cast to float for consistent data type in pyramid
>   --> 197     image = img_as_float(image)
>       198 
>       199     layer = 0
>
> D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\dtype.py in
>   img_as_float(image, force_copy)
>       411 
>       412     """
>   --> 413     return convert(image, np.floating, force_copy)
>       414 
>       415
>
> D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\dtype.py in convert(image,
>   dtype, force_copy, uniform)
>       124     if not (dtype_in in _supported_types and dtype_out in _supported_types):
>       125         raise ValueError("Can not convert from {} to {}."
>   --> 126                          .format(dtypeobj_in, dtypeobj_out))
>       127 
>       128     def sign_loss():
>
> ValueError: Can not convert from object to float64.
>
> **

Comment: Can you try `from skimage import io; io.use_plugin('matplotlib')`? Source: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/438

Comment: No change sir.. Please help , I am stuck in this error from last few days.

Comment: Are you sure the error is from the same part of the code you have shared? I do not see ` for img1 in pyramid_gaussian(img, downscale=2):` in any part of the code